# visual studio bug annoying, any fix?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Running visual studio 2008 sp1. When I go to run without debugging a web app, it open 2 IE browser windows? There is nothing in my code that is doing this! I cant seem to find anything on how to fix this. Has anyone run into this? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple web projects?

Check the startup options on the Web tab in the Project Settings and see what they're set to.

If that doesn't help, try creating a new project and see if it does the same. If not, try diffing the csproj files (or csproj.user if you've set it to store settings in a separate file).